# Prove that $([-1,1]^d,\|\cdot\|^d)$ is totally bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, metric-spaces

I have trouble understanding the following proof:

Consider the metric space $([-1,1]^d, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$. Let $\epsilon >0$. Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{1}{n} <\epsilon$. Let $I_n = \{-n, -n+1, \ldots, n-1, n\}$. Now $B_\epsilon\bigg(\dfrac{k_1}{n},\ldots,\dfrac{k_d}{n}\bigg):k_1,\ldots,k_d\in I_n$ is a finite collection of balls of radius $\epsilon$ which has a union which contains $[-1,1]^d$. Indeed, if $x\in[-1,1]^d$, then we can find $k_1,\ldots,k_d\in I_n$ such that $k_j\leq x_j\leq k_{j+1}$. Now one can check that $x\in B_\epsilon\bigg(\dfrac{k_1}{n},\ldots,\dfrac{k_d}{n}\bigg)$ and we have that $([-1,1]^d,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is totally bounded.

**Question:** How would you show that $B_\epsilon\bigg(\dfrac{k_1}{n},\ldots,\dfrac{k_d}{n}\bigg)$ has a union which contains $[-1,1]^d$? I find it really hard to imagine how many balls you would need to cover a set that can no longer be visualised. I've tried think about it in the following way:

Suppose that we just consider $(a,b)$, an interval on the real line $\mathbb{R}$. Given $\epsilon >0$, I think we would need $\dfrac{b-a}{\epsilon}$ balls with radius $\epsilon$ to cover the entire interval. Consider now $(a,b)\times (c,d)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Given $\epsilon$, I think we would need $\dfrac{b-a}{\epsilon}\times \dfrac{d-c}{\epsilon}$ balls with radius $\epsilon$ to cover $(a,b)\times (c,d)$. If I now take a look at $[-1,1]^d$, this reasoning would mean that it would take $\bigg(\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}\bigg)^d$ balls with radius $\epsilon$ to cover $[-1,1]^d$. What would the union of these balls look like?

Comment: How about invoking the Heine Borel theorem.  $[-1,1]^d$ is compact and therefore it is totally bounded?  You can also do this with an evenly spaced lattice of  points.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Thanks, I will definitely do so! Nevertheless, I would really like to know how this proof works. I think it would help me a lot!

Comment: Your idea is correct, up to the fact that $(2/\varepsilon)^d$ is not an integer so you need to floor it. The idea to see what happens in low dimensions is great, because it generalises straightforwardly. In the end the union of balls that you get is a little cloud containing the hypercube.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Oh yeah that's right!